# Why in the weak topology, every neighborhood of $x_0$ contain a line passing through $x_0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ a normed vector space with infinite dimension (it's supposed Banach, but I don't think that it's usefull). To prove that $$S=\{x\in E\mid \|x\|=1\}$$ is not closed, we prove that $$\{x\in E\mid \|x\|<1\}\subset \bar S.$$
And we did as follow : we proved that for all neighborhood $V$ of $x_0\in \{x\in E\mid \|x\|<1\}$ there are $t_0>0$ and $y_0\in E$, $y_0\neq 0$ s.t. $$x_0+t_0y_0\in V\cap S\tag{*}$$ (and thus $V\cap S\neq \emptyset$).

As I remark I have that : The property $(*)$ mean that all neighborhood of $x_0$ contain a line passing through $x_0$.

**Question :** I don't really understand why $(*)$ tel us that there is a line in $V$. We don't have $x_0+ty_0\in V$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$, only that there is $t_0$ s.t. $x_0+t_0y_0\in V$. Could someone explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This presumably is intended to refer to the *proof* of property $(*)$, not the statement of property $(*)$.  If you examine the proof you will see that actually the proof shows that $x_0+ty_0\in V$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  (The specific choice of $t_0$ is just to get a point which is also in $S$.)

Comment: oouupppss... Indeed, it's not written, but yes it $x_0+ty_0\in V$. Thanks a lot :)